# Как наиболее выгодно для памяти убедиться что массив содержит только разрешенные значения?

Tags: java

Какой метод можно применить для такой задачи:

-> получаем массив byte
-> прежде чем передать его в обработку, нужно убедиться что массив содержит только разрешенные значения (если надо, могу их запихнуть в отдельный массив/коллекцию) // самих значений около 20, значения добавляться или меняться не будут в будущем.

-> дальнейшие действия с массивом, если посторонних значений не выявлено

По идее, можно решить через ифы (если немного значений), либо написать отдельный boolean метод с перебором. Также наверняка есть готовые методы в языке типа `ContainsAll()` (он не подходит вроде бы). Еще не понятно что из этого будет эффективнее с точки зрения использования памяти.

Что эффективнее использовать в данном случае?

Comment: Не обязательно чтобы все значения были в массиве, главное чтобы не было посторонних значений

Comment: Пока вот такой спагетти-иф:   if ((inputToByte[i] >= 47 && inputToByte[i] <= 57) || inputToByte[i] == 32 || inputToByte[i] == 42 || inputToByte[i] == 43 || inputToByte[i] == 45 ||
                    inputToByte[i] == 73 || inputToByte[i] == 77 || inputToByte[i] == 68 || inputToByte[i] == 67 || inputToByte[i] == 86 || inputToByte[i] == 88) который можно потом спрятать в отдельный метод.

Comment: В каком смысле эффективнее?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Быстрее всего проверка выполняется при помощи преобразования массива допустимых байт в `Set<Byte>`, тогда можно написать метод для быстрой проверки при помощи `Set::contains`:

```java
static Set<Byte> allowed = Set.of((byte)1, (byte)2, (byte)3, (byte)5, (byte)20);
    
public static boolean allGood(byte ... arr) {
    for (byte b : arr) {
        if (!allowed.contains(b)) return false;
    }
    return true;
}

    
public static boolean allGood(byte[] arr) {
    for (byte b : arr) {
        if (!allowed.contains(b)) return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Тест:

```java
byte[] byteArray = {3, 2, 2, 1, 1, 5, 2};

System.out.println(allGood(byteArray));                    // true
System.out.println(allGood((byte) 4, (byte)20, (byte)22)); // false
```

---

Аналогично, можно использовать массив битов `BitSet`, так как его максимальная длина составит не более 256:

```java
public static boolean allGood(BitSet allowed, byte ... arr) {
    System.out.print(Arrays.toString(arr) + " -> ");
    for (byte b : arr) {
        if (!allowed.get(0xFF & b)) return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Тест:

```java
byte[] allowedValues = {1, 2, 3, 5, 20, -1, -128};
BitSet allowed = new BitSet(256);
for (byte b : allowedValues) {
    allowed.set(b & 0xFF, true);
}

byte[] byteArray = {3, 2, 2, 1, 1, 5, 2, -1};
System.out.println(allGood(allowed, byteArray));
System.out.println(allGood(allowed, (byte) 4, (byte)20, (byte)22));
System.out.println(allGood(allowed, (byte) -1, (byte)20, (byte)-128));
```

Результат:

```
[3, 2, 2, 1, 1, 5, 2, -1] -> true
[4, 20, 22] -> false
[-1, 20, -128] -> true
```

Comment: Анонимные минусаторы, хоть бы озвучили ваши претензии

Answer (score 1):

Булев массив хранящий истину для хороших байт:

```
    private static final boolean[] good = new boolean[256];
    static {
        String s = " *+-0123456789CDILMVX";
        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); ++i){
            good[s.charAt(i)] = true;
        }
    };

    private static boolean isGood(byte b) {
        return good[Byte.toUnsignedInt(b)];
    }

    private static boolean isGood(byte[] bytes) {
        for (byte b : bytes) {
            if (!isGood(b)) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(isGood(new byte[]{48, 49}));
    }
```